# How to get all research upgrades in Watch Dogs 2?

Tags: watch-dogs-2

I've reached level 22 and finished the story mode. From level 22 you don't seem to get research points for level upgrades and I must have been all over the map and collected all research points I could find. I still have like 5 upgrades to do. I can't imagine that I've missed about 40 research points (required to do the 5 updates).

Is it possible to do all upgrades from the main game, or are you required to buy and play DLC to get the remaining points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the DLC won't get you new research points. Every now and then I find a new research point. So it seems they are all discoverable. I'm now left to the upgrades I don't really need, so I won't bother finding them all. If you like to find them all you can use a [map with all the research locations](http://guides.gamepressure.com/watchdogs2/guide.asp?ID=37898).